# EMBED PROBLEM, FIELD VALUES MAY NOT BE EMPTY

Tags: javascript, discord.js

this embed code results in an error, can someone help me? this is a unban command for discord.js v12

```
let unbanEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Unban")
.setColor("#f5a442")
.addField("Usuário Desbanido", `${unbannedMember} com o ID ${unbannedMember.id}`)
.addField("Desbanido Por", `<@${message.author.id}> com o ID ${message.author.id}`)
.addField("Desbanido no Chat", message.channel)
.addField("Na Hora", message.createdAt)
.addField("Pelo Motivo", reason)
.setFooter("Todos os Direitos Reservados © Bunny Boy")
```

embed error.

```
(node:139) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
    at Function.normalizeField (/home/runner/coelhao/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:432:23)
    at /home/runner/coelhao/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:452:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeFields (/home/runner/coelhao/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:451:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (/home/runner/coelhao/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:266:42)
    at MessageEmbed.addField (/home/runner/coelhao/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:257:17)
    at Object.module.exports.run (/home/runner/coelhao/commands/unban.js:27:6)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: `reason` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

in
`.addField("Pelo Motivo", reason)`
reason appears to be undefined.

you can use

`.addField("Pelo Motive", reason || "None provided")